# Tableau: import JSON data from simple REST call

Tags: json, rest, tableau-api

I have a REST API (served by an external server) replying JSON formatted data.

From what I read from Tableau doc, there's available:
- WebDataConnector but you have to add a JS overload on your webpages, not very suitable for REST APIs
- importing JSON data from file, but doesn't answer my issue

Isn't there a simple way to integrate JSON data requested via REST call ?

Comment: As amazing as it might appear, seems that Tableau devs never thought that such interface is almost mandatory nowadays. Only light solution found is via json file. Welcome back in the 90s!

Answer (score 1):

You can use WDC, you are wrong that its not suitable for REST API. So you basically need to create 2 functions for getting fields and data for your datasets from API:

```
    myConnector.getSchema = function (schemaCallback) {
    $.ajax({
        url: apiurl + JSON.parse(tableau.connectionData)['diggerID'] + "/sessions/last/data/one",
        type: "GET",
        headers: {
            'Authorization': 'Token ' + JSON.parse(tableau.connectionData)['apiKey']
        },
        success: function(response){
            var flatten = objectFlatten(response)
            var columns = []
            for (var key in flatten) {
                var id = key.replace(/[^A-Za-z0-9_]+/g, '')
                columns.push({
                    id: id,
                    alias: key,
                    dataType: tableauType(flatten[key])
                })
            }
            var table = {
              id: "digger_" + JSON.parse(tableau.connectionData)['diggerID'],
              alias: tableau.connectionName,
              columns: columns
            }
            schemaCallback([table]);
        },
        error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
            tableau.abortWithError("Unable to get data. Make sure you used proper API key and you have at least one session for selected digger with dataset.");
        }
    });
};
myConnector.getData = function (table, doneCallback) {
    $.ajax({
        url: apiurl + JSON.parse(tableau.connectionData)['diggerID'] + "/sessions/last/data",
        type: "GET",
        headers: {
            'Authorization': 'Token ' + JSON.parse(tableau.connectionData)['apiKey']
        },
        success: function(response){
            var data = []
            for (var i=0; i < response.length; i++) {
                var flatten = objectFlatten(response[i])
                var rec = {}
                for (var key in flatten) {
                    var id = key.replace(/[^A-Za-z0-9_]+/g, '')
                    rec[id] = flatten[key]
                }
                data.push(rec)
            }
            table.appendRows(data);
            doneCallback();
        },
        error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
            tableau.abortWithError("Unable to get data. Make sure you used proper API key and you have at least one session for selected digger with dataset.");
        }
    });
};
```

For complete code you can check out for source code on github: https://github.com/Diggernaut/diggernaut-wdc

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/18651822)

Comment: Question was how to get Tableau work with REST API, essential part of answer was: "use WDC", link to source code was given as example of succesfull implementation WDC to connect to REST API